# Use Django's Generic Date Views There's a 404 error

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from blog import views

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [

    path('archive/<int:year>/<str:month>/<int:day>/',
         views.PostDAV.as_view(), name='post_day_archive'),
    path('archive/today/', views.PostTAV.as_view(), name='post_today_archive'),
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.views.generic.dates import DayArchiveView, TodayArchiveView

from blog.models import Post


class PostDAV(DayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'


class PostTAV(TodayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
```

error code

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/today/
Raised by:  blog.views.PostTAV
No posts available

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

When using DayArchiveView, template is opened, but 404 error occurs when using TodayArchiveView.On the official website of the library (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/), I'm sure TodayArchiveView and DayArchiveView have the same template name, but why does 404 error occur only when I use TodayArchiveView? Why does the TodayArchiveView alone have 404 errors when both use the same template? Just in case, I named the template for TodayArchiveView as something else and tried using another template, but there is still a 404 error. Is there anything I missed? I'm sorry for my poor English.

stack trace

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 20, 2020 - 12:05:42
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'myblog.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[20/May/2020 12:05:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2135
[20/May/2020 12:05:51] "GET /blog/archive/ HTTP/1.1" 200 771
Not Found: /blog/archive/today/
[20/May/2020 12:05:57] "GET /blog/archive/today/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1731
```

The first 404 error occurred because I haven't set up the homepage yet. Please ignore it.

Comment: can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace was added. I'm ashamed, but I've just learned what stack trace is from your comments. Is this the stack trace I added?